# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку button печатался текст в textarea

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Появился вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку button печатался текст в textarea. А вернее: нажимается кнопочка с надписью "<p>" - в поле textarea выводится "<p>". Вероятно через событие onclick, но у меня что-то не получается. И еще, переменная text из поля textarea обрабатывается функцией htmlspecialchars. Как сделать, чтобы теги <p>,</p>,<br> пропускались, а остальные нет? Спасибо.

Comment: Вот, с импровизировал по быстрому

    <button id="mybutton"> <р> </button><br>
            <textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
            <script>
           $('#mybutton').click(function(){$('#mytext').val("<p>")})
            </script>

<button id="mybutton"> <р> </button><br>
        <textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
        <script>
       $('#mybutton').click(function(){$('#mytext').val("<p>")})
        </script>

Comment: @abibock_un, сымпровизировал( у вас в этом слове было две ошибки=) )? Это ж элементарная хрень, которую ты и то сделал неверно! Тег <p> в кнопочке будет восприниматься, как незакрытый тег абзаца. Тебе следовало бы юзать свойство value у input button.

Comment: 
Разве ошибки в слове сымпровизировал здесь на что-то влияют? Человеку надо было помочь с "элементарной хренью". Конечно, value было бы правильно, но мне показалось так нагляднее. В кнопке тэг абзаца написан кириллицей.

Comment: Да, abibock_un, на серьёзное восприятие человека =)

     Разве ошибки в слове сымпровизировал здесь на что-то влияют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>

function push(but, id, tag) {
    document.getElementById(id).value += tag;
}
</script>

<textarea id='put'></textarea>

<button onclick="push(this, 'put', '<p>')">&lt;p&gt;</button> 
<button onclick="push(this, 'put', '</p>')">&lt;/p&gt;</button>
```

Еще:

```
<script>
function push(but, id) {
    document.getElementById(id).value += but.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;|&gt;)/g, function(mth) {
        return mth == '&lt;'?'<':'>';
    });
}
</script>

<textarea id='put'></textarea>

<button onclick="push(this, 'put')">&lt;p&gt;</button> 
<button onclick="push(this, 'put')">&lt;/p&gt;</button>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $('.push').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('put').value += this.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;|&gt;)/g, function(mth) {
            return mth == '&lt;'?'<':'>';
        });
    });

});
</script>

<textarea id='put'></textarea>

<button class='push'>&lt;p&gt;</button> 
<button class='push'>&lt;/p&gt;</button>
```

Мой способ исключения тегов:

```
$arrays_tags = array(array('<p>', '</p>', '<br>'), array('[p]', '[/p]', '[br]'));

$text = str_replace($arrays_tags[0], $arrays_tags[1], $text);

$text = htmlspecialchars($text);

$text = str_replace($arrays_tags[1], $arrays_tags[0], $text);

var_dump($text);
```

Comment: lampa, спасибо большое, ваш код работает, только почему-то при нажатии на кнопку открывается обработчик, это ведь кнопка не submit, почему так происходит?

Comment: Уважуха за native подход)

Comment: А, тип не указан)

Comment: @Регина что за обработчик? Код очень простой и ничего не должно дополнительно происходить.

 @nolka я предпочитаю пользоваться http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: Все работает, просто тип button не был указан. Но символы < и > все равно заменяются на &lt; и &gt;. Как этого избежать?

Comment: @Регина, думаю пока.

Comment: @Регина обновил пост.

Comment: @Регина смысл в том, что мы функцией str_replace заменяем наши теги <p>, </p>... на [p], [/p]... которые после обработки остаются такими же, как и до обработки функцией htmlspecialchars. Дальше смы запускаем функцию str_replace еще раз, только теперь замена тегов происходит обратно, из [p] в <p>.

Comment: Теперь все ясно и просто!